# delayed_job restart from capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

Here is what I have in my enviornment.rb. I understand there have been
issues with restarting because of a bug in the "daemons" gem and that
the ghazel-daemons fixes it. But its not working in my case. I am
using the collectiveidea 2.1.0--pre version of DJ, rails 2.3.5.

```
config.gem 'delayed_job', :source => 'http://rubygems.org', :version
=> "2.1.0.pre"
    config.gem "ghazel-daemons", :lib => "daemons", :source => 'http://
gems.github.com'
    gem "ghazel-daemons"
    require "daemons"
```

But I stil can't get delayed_job to restart from capistrano.

```
    desc "Restart the delayed_job process"
    task :delayed_job_restart, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path};#{get_rails_env} script/delayed_job
restart"
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using 2.0.3 without problems in 2.3.8, I believe that 2.1.0 is for rails 3 ([reference](http://wiki.github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/changelog)).

I have not heard about the `ghazel-daemons` gem, I currently have the following patch within the rails application running against with the daemons gem:

patch:  http://blog.rapleaf.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/daemons_extension.rb

writeup: http://blog.rapleaf.com/dev/2008/02/15/making-sure-ruby-daemons-die/

Answer (score 0):

I'd say stick with the ghazel-daemons gem over monkey patching daemons.

Geoff's right though that you shouldn't be using delayed_job 2.1 with rails < 3.0, at time of writing the lastest rails 2 compatible delayed_job gem is 2.0.7.